# Answers created before questions

Tags: bug, questions

I have seen some questions on StackOverflow, in which, answers are created earlier than questions' creation time. How is that possible?

For example, question "[How can I cause an instruction cache miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588567/how-can-i-cause-an-instruction-cache-miss?answertab=active#tab-top)"
   - The question is asked on May 14 '12 at 17:57
   - All answers are created on Mar 21 '12

Comment: The post [was merged](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10588567/timeline#history_8f7f2a1a-8b06-4ea3-a505-875a69d5437c) with another one. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question

Comment: The asker is traveling faster than the speed of light. Or maybe @ivarni is correct. I like my answer better.